# how to create a table in R?

Tags: r

there is a data in R,the object is :

```
> y
[0,1000) [1000,1500) [1500,2000) [2000,2500) [2500,3000) [3000,3500) [3500,5000]   
     13          44          29          16           9           3           5 
> attributes(y)
$dim
[1] 7
$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
[1] "[0,1000)"    "[1000,1500)" "[1500,2000)" "[2000,2500)" "[2500,3000)" "[3000,3500)" "[3500,5000]"
$class
[1] "table"
```

if i want to produce it ,how can i crate a table such as `y` in R?
if there it is no vector,i want to create a `y` ,not to use `table(cut(some_vector))`,
i want to create it directly ,not according to `table(cut(some_vector))`.

i have solved it ,can it be simplyfied?

```
y<-c(13,44,29,16,9,3,5) 
names(y)<-c( "[0,1000)","[1000,1500)","[1500,2000)","[2000,2500)","[2500,3000)"," [3000,3500)","[3500,5000]")  
as.table(y)->z
```

`z` is what i wanted.

Comment: `?cut` is likly what you're after.  Or explicitly, `table(cut(some_vector))`

Comment: what does that mean "Create it directly"  You want to manually type it in?   Just go right ahead  `y <- ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read.table` is your friend.  use the `text=..` argument

---

```
nms <- read.table(text="[0,1000) [1000,1500) [1500,2000) [2000,2500) [2500,3000) [3000,3500) [3500,5000]", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
y   <- read.table(text="     13          44          29          16           9           3           5 ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

y <- as.table(as.numeric(unlist(y)))
dimnames(y) <- list(nms)
```

---

```
> attributes(y)
$dim
[1] 7

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
[1] "[0,1000)"    "[1000,1500)" "[1500,2000)" "[2000,2500)" "[2500,3000)" "[3000,3500)"
[7] "[3500,5000]"


$class
[1] "table"
```